# Getting errors in showing alert dialog from another activity(to prevent the activity from destroyed)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog, android-context

Don't know why, no one is trying to solve this issue.

Here I'm fully messed up. I'm creating an android app and currently facing problem in operation of 3 activities.

I have **Activity1**, **Activity2** and **Activity3**.

**Activity1**: getting data in `AsyncTask(background)` and showing listView. Showing alertDialog with `onClick` action on listView Item.

I'm using constructor in `AsyncTask`

```
        public NameAsyncTask(Context cxt) {
            context = cxt;
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    context, dataList,
                    R.layout.list_incident, new String[]{"refName", "sub", "status", "categ", "createTime", "organisation"},
                    new int[]{R.id.in_name, R.id.sub, R.id.status,R.id.categ_show, R.id.created_time_show, R.id.cust_name});
            binder = new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder() {
                @Override
                public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data, String textRepresentation) {
                    if (view.equals((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.status))) {
                        statusText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.status);
                        if (data.equals("Unresolved"))
                            statusText.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                        else if (data.equals("In Progress"))
                            statusText.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow));
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            };
        }
```

I'm calling `AsyncTask` class as `new NameAsyncTask(Activity1.this).execute();`

**Activity2**: showing the details of an item of listView as it is clicked. At last calling `finish()` as it goes in `Activity3`.

**Activity3**: updating details of the item and calling `AsyncTask(background)` of the `1st activity` as `new NameAsyncTask(Activity3.this).execute();` so that item will be removed in `first activity` and the listView will be updated. calling `finish()` and it'll directly goes to 1st activity(since 2nd activity is already finished).

Now the problem is, if again I click on listView item, it throws error as

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
                                                                 at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:149)
                                                                 at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:157)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:113)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:291)
                                                                 at com.lavazza.IncidentServiceActivity$GetPendingIncidents$2.onItemClick(IncidentServiceActivity.java:267)
                                                                 at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
                                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1156)
                                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3121)
                                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:4048)
                                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3807)
                                                                 at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:10023)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2626)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2307)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:413)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1808)
```

on this line

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity1.this);
```

Not sure, whether `Activity1` is also getting distroyed.

since `adapter` for listView and `binder` works for both contexts of activities. but in `alertDialog` it doesn't work. When I declare `final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);` in the constructor. It works fine in **Activity1**.

If I execute the `AsyncTask` from **Activity3** with `Activity1Obj.new GetPendingIncidents(Activity3.this).execute();`  it throws error as

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@1a8ec93 is not valid; is your activity running?
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:679)
                                                                   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:342)
                                                                   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
                                                                   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:322)
                                                                   at com.lavazza.IncidentServiceActivity$GetPendingIncidents$2.onItemClick(IncidentServiceActivity.java:338)
```

here the **Activity1** is automatically destroyed which I believe. Correct me if I'm wrong.

I already tried

->changing `context` in declaration of alertDialog as `getParent`, `getApplicationContext`, `getBaseContext`. Nothing worked.

I've to show `alertDialog` after returning from `Activity3`.

Is there anyone to help me out. Still I'm thinking how to perform this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MyApplication.getContext()` instead of context(etc. `Activity1.this` ).

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

**MyApplication.java**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();  
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String app_name = MyApplication.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);  
        Log.d("App name", app_name);    
    }
}
```

Comment: here `MyApplication` refer to `app name`?

Comment: `MyApplication` is like a main Activity. You have to describe in manifesto and create a class that extends `Application`.

Comment: This class will be just blank or I've to describe some function or variable in this?

Comment: basically `MyApplication` will return the value of `getApplicationContext()` ....Why can't I use directly

Answer (score 0):

You only need to finish you activity3 that is showing alertdialog , no need to finish activity1 as well as 2.

and also use 
context.finish();
where context = your_activity.this;

Hope it will help you.

Comment: the alertdialog is in the `Activity1`. After calling the `Activity1.AsyncTask` in `Activity3`, 3rd Activity is finished. Then directly I'll be in `Activity1` though `Activity2' is already finished. And when I clicked another item of  `listView` in `Activity1`, It throws error as `is Your activity is running?` here my current activity is 1st one.